# alter the direction of loop dynamically

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to come up with an algorithm for an "approaching" behavior between two integers. Basically, given two integers, `a` and `b`, i want `a` to "approach" `b`, even if `b` is less than `a`. The way i think this should look is a swapping of the loop incrementer function:

```
for (var i = a; approachCond(i, a, b); approachDir(i,a, b)) {
   // some fn(a, b);
}
```

where

```
approachCond(i, a, b) {
 return a < b ? i < b :  i > b;
}
```

and

```
approachDir(i, a, b) {
 return a < b ? i++ : i--
}
```

However, when i try doing this the browser freezes (Chrome). Does anyone know how to dynamically alter the direction of a loop?

Comment: have an if else with a different for loop in each one

Comment: Thats what im doing now, but i want to avoid that if a more elegant solution is possible.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a little clearer to read if you just use a `while` loop:

```js
'use strict';
let a = 12, b = 6;

let i = a;

while (i !== b) {
  console.log(i);
  i += a < b ? 1 : -1;
}
```

I even left the cute ternary since people seem so opposed to if-statements these days.

Comment: Arent while loops supposed to be way less performant than for loops?

Comment: @dopatraman nope; in any case that is likely a micro-optimization and if it becomes a problem you can jsperf it.

Comment: This makes sense to me but for some reason its crashing my browser.

Comment: There is also no way to make a while loop inclusive =/

Answer (score 2):

Your browser freezes because you're not altering the correct `i`. You're only manipulating the `i` that is in the `approachDir` function. If you return it & set the `for` scope `i` to the new value, it will work.

Try:

```
for (var i = a; approachCond(i, a, b); i = approachDir(i,a, b)) {
   // some fn(a, b);
}

approachDir(i, a, b) {
    return a < b ? i + 1 : i - 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though you are overcomplicating something that is not that hard. You can just set the step to positive or negative. e.g.

```
var a = 20;
var b = 5;

for (var step = a > b ? -1 : +1; a != b; a += step)
{
     console.log(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `approachDir`. `i++` and `i--` are **post**-increment and **post**-decrement. That means they update the variable **after** they return its original value. So the function is returning the original value, not the updated one.  To update the variable before returning, you should use `++i` or `--i`.

But you don't need to use an increment operator at all, since the local variable is going away immediately. Just return the new value.

```
function approachDir(i, a, b) {
    return a < b ? i + 1 : i - 1;
}
```

You also need to reassign the variable in the loop:

```
for (var i = a; approachCond(i, a, b); i = approachDir(i, a, b)) {
    ...
}
```

The way you wrote your code, you assumed that variables are passed by reference, not by value, so that the increment in the function would modify the caller's variable.

Comment: You missed the fact that the returned value isn't used in the `for` scope

Comment: Still won't fix it, since the problem is that the return value isn't being assigned anywhere. The loop runs forever because the values of i in the loop itself are never being changed.

Comment: How do i port the i from the function scope to the loop's scope?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to change `approachDir` to return a positive or negative value based on if `a>b`. The middle statement can include an || and work either way.

```js
function approachDir(a, b){
  return a>b?-1:1;
}
var a=3;
var b=1;
for (var i = a; i<b||i>b; i+=approachDir(a, b)) {
   console.log(i);
}
a=1;
b=3;
for (var i = a; i<b||i>b; i+=approachDir(a, b)) {
   console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: What is the `||` doing? Shouldnt we choose one condition?

Comment: `i < b || i > b` is simply `i !== b`.

Comment: @dopatraman like Mathletics mentioned as long as `i!=b` the loop will run, the increment will move in the right direction depending on if `a>b` or not

Answer (score 0):

I made a slight change to @mathletics answer:

```
  function loopDynamic(from, to) {
    const direction = from < to ? 1 : -1;
    let i = from

    while (i!== to) {
      // do whatever with i

      i += direction;
    }
  }
```