# Direction-agnostic for-loop, how to include final value in iteration?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31710513/619177), I want to create a for-loop that runs regardless of whether the start value is greater or less than the end value:

```
function iterateStartToEnd(startVal,endVal){
    var val=startVal;
    for (var step=val>endVal?-1:+1;val!=endVal;val+=step){
        //do something with iterated val
        console.log(val);
    }
}

startVal=6;
endVal=3;
iterateStartToEnd(startVal,endVal);
```

Because of the `val!=endVal` in the for-loop definition (which seems to be necessary as part of making the loop direction-agnostic), the final value is not included in the iteration, so in this case the output looks like:

```
6
5
4
```

But I want to include the final value `endVal`.  Is there any way to include it in the for-loop, or do I have to include it using the following:

```
function iterateStartToEnd(startVal,endVal){
    var val=startVal;
    for (var step=val>endVal?-1:+1;val!=endVal;val+=step){
        //doSomething(val);
        console.log(val);
    }
}

startVal=6;
endVal=3;
iterateStartToEnd(startVal,endVal);

//doSomething(endVal);
console.log(endVal);
```

Comment: End limits are usually exclusive anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to stop when the value goes *beyond* the endVal:

```
val != endVal + step
```